# Ros subscriber - Passing msg data to the callback

Tags: ros, c++, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom msg data file containing the data field names that I wish to use for a project.

This data is published in a topic, that is written in Python. What I am trying to do is create a C++ script (Subscriber) that subscribes to this topic and displays a particular name within the msg data.

So far I have written the following:

```
void callback(const leap_motion_sensor::leap& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard" + msg);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "features");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    //ros::Timer timer1 = n.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.08), callback);

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/leapmotion/data", callback);

    ros::spin();

    
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning message:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1390260279.317426] Could not process inbound connection: topic t
types do not match: [leap_motion_sensor/leap] vs. [leap_motion_sensor/leapros]
{'topic': '/leapmotion/data', 'tcp_nodelay': '0', 'md5sum': 
'3e9a0dc7fd1a98f1d7489e9011c78807', 'type': 'leap_motion_sensor/leap', 'callerid': 
'/features'}
```

Here is what the msg file contains:

Header header

float64[3] hand_direction
float64[3] hand_normal
float64[3] hand_palm_pos
float64 hand_pitch
float64 hand_roll
float64 hand_yaw

I just want to copy the data from the "hand_direction" into a `std::vector<float>` Is this possible and if so, what needs to be in my callback function in order to be able to pass through this data?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119836/ros-subscriber---passing-msg-data-to-the-callback/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you aren't publishing and receiving the same message types; the message type that you're subscribing to and the message type that is being published must match.

For your example, it looks like you should be subscribing to the `leap_motion_sensor/leapros` message type (`leap_motion_sensor::leapros` in C++).

From there, you should be able to access the hand_direction data with `msg->hand_direction`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0